# 'RootLayout' object has no attribute 'image'

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I made a program with **Kivy** to get a random image out when the button is pressed.
I wrote the code but when I want to change the source I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'RootLayout' object has no attribute 'image'`

Python:

```
class MinimalApp(App):
    images_defenders2 = list(images_defenders)
    title = 'My App'
    def build(self):
        number = random.randrange(0, length_code_list1)
        img = (images_attackers[number]) #The variable with the random photo
        print(img)
        root = RootLayout()
        return(root)
class RootLayout(AnchorLayout):
   def say_hello(self):
       def callback(self):
           fonte = StringProperty('tachanka2.jpg')
           self.image.source = (fonte)
           self.image.fonte = "tachanka2.jpg"
       callback(self)  
   pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MinimalApp().run()
```

kv:

```
#:kivy 1.7.2
#:import kivy kivy
#:import random random

<RootLayout>:
    anchor_x: 'center'                              
    anchor_y: 'center'
    Image:
        id: image
        source: 'nokk.png'
        size: self.texture_size
   AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'

    Button:
        text: 'Attacco'
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
        font_size:64
        on_press: {root.say_hello()}
   AnchorLayout:
    anchor_x: 'right'
    anchor_y: 'bottom'

    Button:
        text: 'Difesa'
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
        font_size:64
```

I tried to change the source directly in the kv file and I succeeded but I need to change it in the python file because I have to make a function that brings out a random photo from the list and puts it in a variable.
Then this variable is put as the source of the image.
So please help me understand why that error comes up and how to fix it.
**The piece of code that causes this error is this:**

```
class RootLayout(AnchorLayout):
    def say_hello(self):
        def callback(self):
            fonte = StringProperty('tachanka2.jpg')
            self.image.source = (fonte)
            self.image.fonte = "tachanka2.jpg"
        callback(self)  
    pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

> AttributeError: 'RootLayout' object has no attribute 'image'

## Root Cause

The attribute / variable, `image` does not exist in the `RootLayout` / `AnchorLayout` object.

## Solution

`image` is an `id` assigned to an `Image` widget in your kv file. Therefore, to access that `Image` object in Python code, you need to add `ids`

- Replace `self.image.source` with `self.ids.image.source`
- Remove `self.image.fonte = "tachanka2.jpg"` because there is no attribute, `fonte` in `Image` widget